# Can I import a function from a file in a folder with Django as I would do with the models or views?

Tags: python, django, function, directory, init

In **Django 3.0**, instead of putting all your models in a single `models.py` file like usual:

```
my_project/
├── my_project/
└── my_app/
    ├── models.py
   ...
```

You can create a `models/` folder and put each model in a separate file and call normally after adding it to an `__init__.py` file.

```
my_project/
├── my_project/
└── my_app/
    ├── models/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── my_models_file.py
    │   └── my_other_models_file.py
   ...
```

The `models/__init__.py` should look like something like this:

```py
from .my_models_file import *
from .my_other_models_file import *
```

And my `models.MyExampleModel` in my `my_models.py` can be called normally in my other files like this:

```py
from .models import MyExampleModel


# My code
```

This is also possible with the `views`.

Here is my question:
Is it possible to proceed the same way with non-Django related files ?

I have several functions in my `views.py` which are **not views**. They don't render anything. These are simple python functions used to make some of them reusable.

```py
# My imports


# My view rendering something


def my_function(arg):
    # Do something


def my_other_function(arg):
    # Do something
```

I would like to put them in a folder and put each function in a separate file. Having something like this:

```
my_project/
├── my_project/
└── my_app/
    ├── my_functions/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── my_functions_file.py
    │   └── my_other_functions_file.py
   ...
```

I tried to import this with something like that without success.

```py
from my_functions.my_functions_file import my_function

def new_function():
    my_function(arg)
```

Is there a similar way to proceed ? The purpose of it is to keep the files as clean and readable as possible. I don't like having a lot of not-view related functions in my `views.py` and I would like to put them in their own folder.

Thank you for your help. Ask for more information if I wasn't clear.

Comment: A quick google for imports - https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/ - this should have the most relevant information for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
from my_app.my_functions.my_functions_file import my_function
```

Comment: My bad, it works perfectly. The problem wasn't there but now it's fixed. So the __init__ isn't needed in this case. Thank you for your help anyway.